# How to Style a React Child Component in a Parent Component in React?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

If I have a Child Component like that:

```
const Div = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
`;
const Div = styled.button`
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
`;
export default class Child extends React.Components{
  render(){
    return <Div><Button>Test</Button></Div>;
  }
}
```

And then I want to add Style to the Parent Component like that:

```
const Div = styled(Child)`
  margin-top: 10px;
`;
export default class Parent extends React.Components{
  render(){
    return <Child/>;
  }
}
```

So I guess this is the wrong approach to handle that? so is there another Way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to add a Property className to the Parent Component and Apply them to the outer Element of Child Class. Then this is working. It is described here in Styled Components Docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components

Answer (score 1):

im new to react and this may be obvious, but why dont you use the inline styling directly on the parent?

```
    const parentStyle = {
      margin-top: "10px"
    }
    export default class Parent extends React.Components{
      render(){
        return <Child style={parentStyle}/>;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is just a design choice but I want to have lower Specifity and with Inline Style I can't override Styles anymore (just with important) but I could do so but I personally like the approach of styled components with class generation more and of couse I can make a hierarchy of styles there easier